# How to get direction of a way in OSM file?

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there any way to find out what direction a road/way runs in from the OSM data file? I have read about oneway being equal to 0,1 and -1 but it doesn't look like all the ways have the "oneway" tag associated with them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the [oneway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway) tag is missing then the way is simply no oneway but can be used in both directions.

The direction of a [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) is defined by its [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). It always runs from the first to the last node. Except if oneway=-1 is present. Then it is the other way around, i.e. it runs from the last to the first node.